# ElasticSearch SHOULD clause does no working as expected for OR logics

Tags: elasticsearch, syntax

my document looks like

```
"userId" : userID,
"products" : """[{"productType":"fakeProductType","productId":"fakeProductId"}]""",
"transactionType" : "charge",
```

Following the documentation https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html, I wrote below query

```
# OR query but does not work yet
POST /index/_search
{ 
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        { "term": { "products": "fakeProductTYpe" }}
      ],
      "should": [
        { "term": { "products": "fakeProductId_1" }},
        { "term": { "products": "fakeProductId_2" }}
      ],
      "minimum_should_match": 1,
      "boost" : 1.0
    }
  }
}
```

to so some search as `(productType = fakeProductType) AND (productId = fakeProductId_1 OR productId = fakeProductId_2)`, while i get a result as below code block

Is there anything I miss in the ES query? Any help would be appreciated!

```
"_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 0,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ ]
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You mistyped field names in your `term` queries

```
{ 
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        { "term": { "productType": "fakeProductTYpe" }}
      ],
      "should": [
        { "term": { "productId": "fakeProductId_1" }},
        { "term": { "productId": "fakeProductId_2" }}
      ],
      "minimum_should_match": 1,
      "boost" : 1.0
    }
  }
}
```

But you could also write it like this, using `terms` query that takes a list of matching values:

```
{ 
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        { "term": { "productType": "fakeProductTYpe" }},
        { "terms": { "productId": ["fakeProductId_1", "fakeProductId_2"] }},
      ]
    }
  }
}
```